# Insert record into the table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I have a `DbContext` object which has a table called 'Employees'.

I have an employee object which I want to insert into the `Employees` tables.

I cannot use the `Employees` directly from the context. I want to access with the table name: is this possible ?

```
 MyContext _ctx;
 Type employee = a.GetType("SC.Employee"));
 object employee = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(emp, employee);

 using (_ctx = new MyContext())
 {
     //I am trying to insert the employee object to my entity. But this doesn't work
     //_customCtx["Employees"].add(employee);
 }
```

Comment: Please explain why you can't access Employees from context. That's the way entities are meant to be manipulated in EntityFramework.

Comment: I want to decide the entity on runtime based on the json object I receive.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you want to deserialize a Json to an Employee Object first, then save this into your context ?

I recommend you to do some like this

```
Employee myNewEmployee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(json_string);

using (var _ctx = new MyContext())
{
   _ctx.Employee.Add(myNewEmployee);
}
```

Comment: he cannot access Employees from context!

Answer (score 0):

Even if, as you said, 'I want to decide the entity on runtime based on the json object I receive' you need the table Employees as an entry point.

So in the context add `DbSet<Employee> Employees`.

Then if the entity you have to work with is determined dynamically you can use reflection to search for 'Employees' on your MyContext type and then work with the selected entity (maybe with dynamics).
But you tipically have a finite sets of Entity to work with so why don't just write ifs to select work with the right entity?

This by the way feels like you are not structuring things the right way at another level or in other places